# R- How do I create transaction matrix for data with varying lengths. Used for Association Mining

Tags: r, sqldf, arules

Description: I have a dataset containing patient IDs and diagnoses IDs. Each patient may have between 1 and 20 diagnoses. [Example of Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEGUE.png)

Goal: I need to transform my data frame into a transaction matrix that will be used for market basket analysis.

Problem: Thus far I have had issues using the normal tools used to make a transactional matrix, I believe because of the varying lengths of each PID record.

What I've Tried: I've used the 'arules' package to attempt to convert my data into a transactional matrix through reading the data in as a transaction matrix. [Example of code used to load in data as Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqVvn.png)

This has resulted in the error:
'Error in read.transactions("intermediate.csv", format = "single", cols = c("pid",  :
'cols' must be a numeric (character is only allowed for header = TRUE)'

Initially, this error leads me to believe that the data types of the columns are incorrect (non-numeric), though I clearly set their datatype as numeric in the lines prior to writing out the file and reading it back in as a transaction. I have confirmed by reading the file back in, not as a transaction, that the file is in my desired formatting.

Any thoughts as to how to proceed? I will be using 'sqldf' to try to make this work too, though I'd much prefer to keep it within the 'arules' library.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it didn't take long to come about the answer but I might leave the question here as an example. Attached is all it took to fix. [Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQQV4.png)